# Overriding parent's singleton method

Tags: ruby

In C#, a regular class cannot inherit from a static class. A similar case for Ruby seems to be:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def test
      "this is test"
    end
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def test
    puts super
  end
end

Bar.new.test # >> error
```

Is there a way for a regular class `Bar` to inherit from `Foo` and override `test`?

Comment: There are no static classes in ruby. This inheritance here works just fine. Bar#test fails to find super method because there's none. `test` that is in Foo lives on another level. Not instances of the class, but the class object itself. Overall, it's not clear what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is there a way for me to call `super` so that `"this is test"` would be printed?

Comment: Yes, define `test` in Bar the same way, as singleton method. This would make `Foo.test` its proper super method.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you've defined `Foo::test` (the "::" meaning it's a class method, as opposed to `Foo#test` if it were an instance method), but the normal (shorthand) way it's written is `def self.test; ... ; end` (which here is the same as `def Foo.test; ... ; end`).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for `Bar` to inherit from `Foo`

You've done that part correctly

> and override `test`?

You need to define `Bar.test` as a class method, but what you have written is an instance method definition (and invocation).  Try

```
class Bar < Foo
  class << self
    def test
      super + ", man"
    end
  end
end

Bar.test
#=> "this is a test, man"
```

There is no such thing as a static class or method in Ruby, so the instance method invocation `Bar.new.test` will never refer to the same thing as the class method invocation `Bar.test` as it might in languages with the concept of static methods.

Comment: So the only way to make it work is to make `test` method inside `Bar` singleton as well?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you're not overriding anything. Another way to see this:  `Foo.new.test` will *not* call your method defined on the class `Foo`. (Protip: don't use the name `test` since that's a method on `Kernel` so the error messages may be more confusing than they need to be.)